# What is the command to open a file from within Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I need the command that can open a file without closing emacs
I have tried `C-X C-F`

Comment: Lower case x and f.

Comment: One thing you may find helpful in the future when you're having a problem with a key-binding is to type C-h b. Emacs will then prompt you to type in the key combination that you're interested in, and give you information about the function (if any) that will be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track, but it's `C-x C-f` rather than the capitalized form `C-X C-F` which would imply the `Shift` key is held in addition to `Control`.  So to be explicit, you want to hold `Control` down while pressing `x` and `f` in succession.
The `C-x C-f` sequence will invoke the `find-file` command under vanilla emacs, which lets you choose a file to open in a new buffer.
See also [Emacs Manual Section 18.2 Visiting Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html#:%7E:text=Emacs%20makes%20a%20new%20buffer,entering%20file%20names%20into%20minibuffers).

Answer (score 1):

Emacs distinguishes between uppercase and lowercase letters.
Emacs doesn't pay attention to the actual pressing of the shift key but it pays attention to the receipt of the key combination, so if you press `C-F` it doesn't matter whether you physically pressed `ctrl+shift+f` or `caps-lock` followed by `ctrl+f`.
The exact combination is `C-x C-f`, without shift or caps-lock.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to hold your 'Ctrl' key and press 'x' followed by 'f', Make sure your capslock is off. and be in editing mode.